# Как исправить ошибку Cannot find symbol, используя команду mvn test?

Tags: java, maven, junit

Создал проект, исходный код которого лежит [здесь](https://github.com/redbeard3/Quiz2/tree/features/tests). (Если вдруг открылась ветка master, то надо перейти на features/tests).

Создал тест (делаю это впервые) для метода ArrayList getPhoneList(String query) класса Phones.java. Сам тест написал в классе PhonesTest.java.

В итоге получилась такая структура у проекта:

`src/main/java/phonebook/` - здесь лежат java-файлы классов.

`src/test/java/phonebook/` - здесь лежит java-файл класса теста.

В файле pom.xml указал зависимость junit.

Запускаю тестирование командой `mvn test`, в результате которого maven выдает ошибку:

```
Compilation failure
src/test/java/phonebook/PhonesTest.java: [7, 17] cannot find symbol
symbol: class Phones
location: package phonebook
```

[image: скрин консоли]

Перепроверил все имена классов, папок, все сходится, в папке phonebook есть файл Phones.java, коде самого теста есть строка `"import phonebook.Phones;"`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть причина этой ошибки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в классе Phones.java не объявлен `package phonebook;`. Поэтому для компилятора `phonebook.Phones` действительно не существует, существует только `Phones` в корневом неймспейсе

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ!